# how to remove element using ElementTree.fromstring

Tags: python, xml

Hello how I can remove element using Python's ElementTree.fromstring.

I want to remove the entire **"cpu block"** from the following xml, would you please help me.

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>udraz</name>
  <uuid>a62e21b0-2111-421e-a27f-1bc7f6b3c46f</uuid>
  <description>My VM</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Nehalem</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Element.remove method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) like so:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

root = ElementTree.fromstring(your_xml_string)    
for elem in root.findall("cpu"):
    root.remove(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove  all elements with tag "cpu"

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.fromstring(xml)
[ tree.remove(elem) for elem in tree.iter() if elem.tag=="cpu"]
```

if you  want remove all elements with any mentions with "cpu" in tag you should use `if elem.tag in "cpu"`